# Using mca package in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to use the [mca package](https://github.com/esafak/mca/blob/master/docs/usage.rst) to do multiple correspondence analysis in Python.

I am a bit confused as to how to use it. With `PCA` I would expect to *fit* some data (i.e. find principal components for those data) and then later I would be able to use the principal components that I found to *transform* unseen data.

Based on the MCA documentation, I cannot work out how to do this last step. I also don't understand what any of the weirdly cryptically named properties and methods do (i.e. `.E`, `.L`, `.K`, `.k` etc).

So far if I have a DataFrame with a column containing strings (assume this is the only column in the DF) I would do something like

```
import mca
ca = mca.MCA(pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True))
```

from what I can gather

```
ca.fs_r(1)
```

is the transformation of the data in `df` and

```
ca.L
```

is supposed to be the eigenvalues (although I get a vector of `1`s that is one element fewer that my number of features?).

now if I had some more data with the same features, let's say `df_new` and assuming I've already converted this correctly to dummy variables, how do I find the equivalent of `ca.fs_r(1)` for the new data

Comment: Judging from the [mca usage guide](https://github.com/esafak/mca/blob/master/docs/usage.rst), you need to use `ca.fs_r_sup(df_new)` to project your new data. Does this help?

Comment: But how do you know from that document? I guess you could infer it because ` mca_counts.fs_r_sup(new_counts, 2)` takes a variable called `new_counts` but does it actually document what each function and property are supposed to do somewhere?

Comment: @JanTrienes you might as well add that as an answer to claim the bounty

Comment: Done. Nevertheless, I feel that my answer can be improved with appropriate background info on MCA. Also, I agree that the package is not very well documented, which makes things harder.

Comment: @JanTrienes Yup, and the single letter variable and function names do not help much either

Comment: You can try looking at [Prince](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince), it is very well documented and easy to use.

Comment: @Axois thanks! This looks great :)  If you know the package, could you post an answer here demonstrating how to use it to fit and transform categorical data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation of the mca package is not very clear with that regard. However, there are a few cues which suggest that `ca.fs_r_sup(df_new)` should be used to project new (unseen) data onto the factors obtained in the analysis.

1. The package author refers to new data as *supplementary data* which is the terminology used in following paper: Abdi, H., & Valentin, D. (2007). [Multiple correspondence analysis](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dominique_Valentin/publication/239542271_Multiple_Correspondence_Analysis/links/54a979900cf256bf8bb95c95.pdf). *Encyclopedia of measurement and statistics*, 651-657.
2. The package has only two functions which accept new data as parameter `DF`: `fs_r_sup(self, DF, N=None)` and `fs_c_sup(self, DF, N=None)`. The latter is to find the column factor scores.
3. The [usage guide](https://github.com/esafak/mca/blob/f2b79ecbf37629902ccdbad2e1a556977c53d370/docs/usage.rst) demonstrates this based on a new data frame which has not been used throughout the component analysis.

Comment: Although this directly answers the question so is technically the correct solution, for anyone reading this it is worth taking a look at the answer by [Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57237247/1011724) for a better alternative to the library in question.

Answer (score 37):

One other method is to use the library [prince](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince#multiple-correspondence-analysis-mca) which enables easy usage of tools such as:

1. Multiple correspondence analysis (MCA)
2. Principal component analysis (PCA)
3. Multiple factor analysis (MFA)

You can begin first by installing with:

```
pip install --user prince
```

To use `MCA`, it is fairly simple and can be done in a couple of steps (just like `sklearn PCA` method.) We first build our dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd 
import prince

X = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/balloons/adult+stretch.data')
X.columns = ['Color', 'Size', 'Action', 'Age', 'Inflated']

print(X.head())

mca = prince.MCA()

# outputs
>>     Color   Size   Action    Age Inflated
   0  YELLOW  SMALL  STRETCH  ADULT        T
   1  YELLOW  SMALL  STRETCH  CHILD        F
   2  YELLOW  SMALL      DIP  ADULT        F
   3  YELLOW  SMALL      DIP  CHILD        F
   4  YELLOW  LARGE  STRETCH  ADULT        T
```

Followed by calling the `fit` and `transform` method.

```
mca = mca.fit(X) # same as calling ca.fs_r(1)
mca = mca.transform(X) # same as calling ca.fs_r_sup(df_new) for *another* test set.
print(mca)

# outputs
>>         0             1
0   0.705387  8.373126e-15
1  -0.386586  8.336230e-15
2  -0.386586  6.335675e-15
3  -0.852014  6.726393e-15
4   0.783539 -6.333333e-01
5   0.783539 -6.333333e-01
6  -0.308434 -6.333333e-01
7  -0.308434 -6.333333e-01
8  -0.773862 -6.333333e-01
9   0.783539  6.333333e-01
10  0.783539  6.333333e-01
11 -0.308434  6.333333e-01
12 -0.308434  6.333333e-01
13 -0.773862  6.333333e-01
14  0.861691 -5.893240e-15
15  0.861691 -5.893240e-15
16 -0.230282 -5.930136e-15
17 -0.230282 -7.930691e-15
18 -0.695710 -7.539973e-15
```

You can even print out the picture diagram of it, since it incorporates `matplotlib` library.

```
ax = mca.plot_coordinates(
     X=X,
     ax=None,
     figsize=(6, 6),
     show_row_points=True,
     row_points_size=10,
     show_row_labels=False,
     show_column_points=True,
     column_points_size=30,
     show_column_labels=False,
     legend_n_cols=1
     )

ax.get_figure().savefig('images/mca_coordinates.svg')
```

[image: mca]

Comment: Above code gives error. Need to remove assignment at mca.transform(X) function. This function returns DataFrame which shouldn't be assigned to mca again.

Comment: Hello looks like the function plot_coordinates() is deprecated and need to use plot() instead. Any ideas on how to do labelling of the plot using plot() function?